# How to make jekyll serve --watch rebuild when an included file is changed?

Tags: jekyll

So the question is pretty much explained in the title. Suppose that I have the following directory structure:

```
./index.html
./_includes/include1
```

And that the content of index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test page for inclusions</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include include1 %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to get the `index.html` rebuilt when the `include1` file is changed?

**Edit:** Just to clarify, `index.html` is regenerated when `index.html` is changed, I want to know how to also get the page regenerated when something that it depends on changes, in this case the `include1` file from the `_includes/` directory.

And, in case it is important:

```
$ jekyll --version
jekyll 1.0.3
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
```

My _config.yml:

```
$ cat _config.yml
timezone: Europe/Amsterdam
```

That is, for the most part I am just running with the [defaults](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/), which seems to work, since it knows where to find the `include1` file.

Answer (score 0):

Using the --watch command should automatically update your site when anything in your directory changes. It even updates the server when you create a new file.

Make sure that you're in your project's directory not im your _site directory. Your projetc dir should look like this:

- _layouts
- _includes
- _site
- _posts
- .. Anything else

If for some reason the --watch command doesn't updatethe server you can always do the jekyll build command on your project directory.

What platform with what version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified, in the question. When one of the files in the "root" directory is changed, it is regenerated, but these pages are not regenerated if one of the _includes files changes.

Comment: could you post your config.yml file?

Comment: have you used the include statement in your layout file? Includes only work in layout files. Also, does your _includes/include1 file have a .html extension? I find it better for layouts and includes to be .html.

Comment: The index.html is exactly as above, that is the file is included from the html, not from a layout. And it does work. I could try renaming the file to .html, since it is more or less a HTML fragment anyway.